# Move block after size atributte of product page [Magento 2]

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, template

I want to move a block and put it after size attribute because when I click this button magento detect that I add to cart:

[image]

I use this to move after add to cart, but I don´t known to move to the other position:

```
    <move element="product.size" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" after=""/>
```

Thaaaanks!!!

Comment: try this solution `<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Promo" after="product.attributes">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">promo</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>`